# Find all the solutions that make the expression a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, integers, perfect-powers

The expression:

$$(2x^2+2x+2y^2+2y+1)(2x^2+2x-2y^2-2y)\tag{1}$$

where:

$x>y,\qquad x,y$ are non-negative integers.

Is it possible to find all $x,y$'s that make $(1)$ a perfect square number?

or how to prove there is no such solution?

Comment: $x = -1, 0$ and $y = -1, 0$ all combinations of it are all solutions. Since you asked non-negative, then $x=0,y=0$ is the only solution

Comment: Is it possible to prove that there is no solution that meets the current requirements: x>y and nonnegative?

Comment: Yes. Take $a = 2x^2 + 2x$, $b = 2y^2 + 2y)$, simplify the expression and it has to be a perfect square. It is a quadratic in $a$ and apply the criteria.

Comment: Then it is an acceptable answer.